# Get-AzureADGroup for groups starting with XX and YY

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I need to know how can I get a list of all groups starting with XX and YY.

So far I've tried

```
Get-AzureADGroup -SearchString 'XX'
Get-AzureADGroup -SearchString 'YY'
Get-AzureADGroup -SearchString 'ZZ'
```

It shows the result, but I was wondering how to do it in one query.

I've also tried

```
$group = 'XX', 'YY', 'ZZ'
foreach($groupNames in $group) {
Get-AzureADGroup}
```

But it shows things it shouldn't and gets every result 3 times.

Comment: `Get-AzureADGroup -SearchString $groupNames` in your loop.

Comment: That actually solved the problem, I apreciate it, if you want to coment it as answer, i'll close the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-SearchString` parameter applies an implicit `StartsWith` functionality. So `-SearchString 'XX'` would match `XX My Group` but not `MY Group XX`. Therefore, you can do the following:

```
$group = 'XX', 'YY', 'ZZ'
foreach($groupName in $group) {
    Get-AzureADGroup -SearchString $groupName
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Get-AzureADGroup` supports OData filters, so you should be able to do a wildcard search for groups starting with `XX` by doing:

```bsh
Get-AzureADGroup -Filter "startswith(Name, 'XX')"
```

With that in mind, we can generate a filter statement like so:

```bsh
# define prefixes
$group = 'XX', 'YY', 'ZZ'

# generate filter clauses and concatenate
$filter = $group.ForEach({"startswith(Name,'${_}')"}) -join ' or '

# retrieve matching groups
Get-AzureADGroup -Filter $filter
```

Comment: As far as I know, `SearchFilter` uses an implicit `StartsWith*` when searching.

Comment: That was perfect! Thank you so much!

Comment: @AdminOfThings add another answer?